# moment isBetween doesn't work using format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I formated 3 dates, start, end and today.

```
let start_date = '20-06-2018',
end_date = '20-06-2018',
today = '20-06-2018'
```

But when I parse the string back and used isBetween it return false.

```
console.log(moment(start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBetween(moment(today, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), moment(end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))) //false?
```

Although start and end is the same day but today should be isBetweeen.

Answer (score 2):

See [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) docs and use inclusivity parameter

> Check if a moment is between two other moments, optionally looking at unit scale (minutes, hours, days, etc). The match is exclusive.
>
> Version **2.13.0** introduces inclusivity. A `[` indicates inclusion of a value. A `(` indicates exclusion. If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed.

```js
let start_date = '20-06-2018',
end_date = '20-06-2018',
today = '20-06-2018'

console.log(moment(start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBetween(moment(today, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), moment(end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')))

console.log(moment(start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBetween(moment(today, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), moment(end_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), null, '[]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```